# To implement EAP-TLS for BYOD devices on a campus wireless network, should you use only machine authentication?

Tags: authentication, byod

Like why would you need user authentication? If someone has an iPhone and is a member of the campus, he would only need a machine certificate for his iPhone so that only it can connect to the network right?

Comment: How does the system know that the iPhone belongs to a member of the campus? That's the purpose of user authentication.

Comment: The person using the iPhone would enroll for a machine certificate for his iPhone the first time he connects to the network.